# Error in data.frame(date = date, city = city, city_other = city_other, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 1, 0

Tags: r

i'm doing a project on weather forecasting. i'm trying this particular code but i keep getting this error
this is the code

```
    collected_data= c()
    for(i in 1:nrow(data_I_want)){

    url <- paste0("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=",data_I_want$latitude[i],"&lon=",data_I_want$longitude[i],"&appid=")

    req <- fromJSON(paste0(url,key))
    city=req$city$name
    city_other=data_I_want$city[i]
    temp=req$list
    date = as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.character(temp$dt)),origin="1970-01-01",tz="GMT")
    rain=temp$rain
    clouds=temp$clouds
    snow=temp$snow
    pressure=temp$pressure
    humidty=temp$humidity
    wind_speed=temp$speed
    z=temp$temp
    day_temperature=z$day   
    min_temperature =z$min 
    max_temperature =z$max 
    night_temperature=z$night
    eve_temperature =z$eve 
    morn_temperature=z$morn 
    zz=temp$weather

  condition = c()
  for(i in 1:length(zz)){
  x=zz[[i]]
  x=x$main
  show(x)
  condition= c(condition,x)
}

this_data=data.frame(date=date,city=city,city_other=city_other,
                     condition=tolower(condition), 
                     rain=rain, 
                     clouds  = clouds,
                     snow=snow,
                     pressure =pressure,
                     humidty=humidty,
                     wind_speed=wind_speed,
                     day_temperature=day_temperature,
                     min_temperature =min_temperature,
                     max_temperature=max_temperature,
                     night_temperature=night_temperature,
                     eve_temperature=eve_temperature,
                     morn_temperature=morn_temperature)
collected_data=cbind(collected_data, this_data)
}

collected_data=   merge(collected_data,data_I_want,by.x="city_other",by.y="city")
save.image(collected_data,file="/home/user/Desktop/weather/we/newstart/newpro/data/collected_data.Rdata")
Sys.sleep(12*60*60)
```

each time i run it i get this error

```
  Error in data.frame(date = date, city = city, city_other = city_other,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 1, 0
```

i tried searching for it but i can't make any head or tail of it.
i would appreciate if anyone could help me with this

Comment: try printing the length of all the inputs to `data.frame`.

Comment: The error is telling you that `data.frame` expected `date`, `city` and `city_other` to have the same length, but they don't so it cannot create rows.

Comment: is it the length of the values in data,city and city_other or is it expecting date,city and city_other to have the same length